# How to implement a slightly more sophisticated IOS device ban feature

Tags: ios, iphone, security, mobile, keychain

I have been programming a iOS app for the best part of 4 months now, and want to implement a feature in which I can ban users devices if they violate the apps policy permanently.(If the app is misused for law breaking etc)

I found another post on stackoverflow however I have a few more extra questions when it comes to how other apps (Snapchat in particular) does this.

I completely didn’t think to actually make this feature until I myself got my device banned from Snapchat, I’ve appealed and contacted support because I  didn’t violate it but in the mean time I’ve done a bit of research -

From what I can gather a unique value can be stored in the keychain. I could use some variation of IP ban. And various obvious techniques. However. Given apple no longer allows apps to get persistent data from a phone such as the IMEI number, how does Snapchat successfully detect that I’ve factory reset my phone? I even use a different Apple ID. And also a different WIFI and IP. So surely there’s no more persistent identifiers? I even tried taking the SIM card out of the phone (I’m European) and putting it in another phone. Then I Continue to set my device up which then sends a code to the other phone. I download Snapchat and they can still detect my phone.

How can I also implement the same thing Snapchat has? Any help would be much appreciated.

so far I’m implementing a keychain and IP ban however I’d like more power like described above in my application.

Comment: Do not use an IP ban - The risk of collateral damage is high due to technologies like CGNAT. You can use the [DeviceCheck Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/accessing_and_modifying_per-device_data) to store two bits of persistent data related to the device.

Comment: @Paulw11 I looked into this and seems to be what I need. Basically I’ll get a true or false back of Apple identifies the device.  On another note is there any way for a user to reset this so the api returns false? Maybe they can put in a request I’m not sure ? Thanks.

Comment: No.  The downside of this solution is that it is associated with the device.  If a banned user sells their device then the new owner will also be banned from your app.  You would need to provide your own mechanism for unbanning a device.  Perhaps a user could contact you and if you agree to unban their device, you can provide them a code that they can enter into your app. Your app would validate the code and clear the banned bit.

Comment: @Paulw11 I see thank you. Is there no way for Apple to reset the identifier themselves? Otherwise this solution might be overkill for what I want. Additionally what information is sent to get a true or false back?

Comment: No, Apple cannot clear it as far as I know.  Apple doesn't disclose how they identify the device, but I imagine they send a value based on your app bundle ID and the device UDID

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you, this is what I needed. Surely this is bad for business on apples side if they can't even reset this when the phone is being resold?

Comment: How would Apple know that the phone was genuinely being resold? The process would be up for abuse with people using it to clear their bans from apps. The new owner may never know that their phone is blocked from a particular app if they never use that app.